# Arranging the numbers from 1 to 999 in a row

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

True or false: The integers $ 1 , 2 , ... , 999 $ can be arranged in a row in such a way that no sum of any number of consecutive elements is an integer multiple of 1000.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is

> true

because

> Arrange them in this order:$$1,998,3,996,5,994,\ldots,995,4,997,2,999$$For $0\le n\le999$ the sum of the first $n$ terms, mod 1000, is $1000-\frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even, and $\frac{n+1}{2}$ if $n$ is odd. Note that these are all different from each other, so the difference between any two is never zero mod 1000. The sum of the terms from the $i$th through the $j$th is the sum of the first $j$ terms, minus the sum of the first $i-1$ terms. Because this is never zero mod 1000, no sum of consecutive elements is a multiple of 1000.